# CallKit get interrupted after upgrade to iOS 15 JitsiMeet is not working properly

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, callkit, jitsi

Till iOS 14 JitsiMeet was working properly after the upgrade to iOS 15 Jitsi meet SDK is not working properly. I have tried the 3.4.2 as well as 5.0.0 versions of JitsiMeet

**There is a different bug in different versions:**

**Jitsi Meet 3.4.2:-**

When call end status green bar is not going and call kit throw - `com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=2`

**Jitsi Meet 5.0.0:-**

When call end status green bar is not going and call kit throw - `com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=4`

During an incoming call, the Jitsi Meet controller dismisses automatically but the audio is ON.

**SDK & iOS version**

Jitsi Meet version: 5.0.0 & 3.4.2

Operating System: iOS15

**Additional information**

I have used pod to install JitsiMeet in my project.

> Thanks In Advance

Comment: Did you get solution for this ? I am facing the same issue.